# Change modal form depending on the button clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table showing the information of the users, with an edit button for each one.

I want to show a modal form with the details for the user I want to edit, but I don't know how to get the details from the list, and passing them to the modal as a model.

Here is my View:

```
@model MyApp.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
    var roles = new List<string> { "Manager", "Admin" };
    var userRoles = (List<string>)ViewData["userRoles"];
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@if (userRoles.Any(u => roles.Contains(u)))
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "update-form", value = "" }))
    {
    <div class="modal fade" id="user-editor" >
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><h3>&times;</h3></a>
            <h3 id="modal-title">Edit User</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Name", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Age", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" />
        </div>
    </div>
    }
}

<table class="table-bordered table-hover" id="tbusers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            @if (userRoles.Any(u => roles.Contains(u)))
            {
                <th>Edit</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var u in users)
        {
            <tr id="@u.Id">
                <td>@u.Name</td>
                <td>@u.Age</td>
                @if (userRoles.Any(u => roles.Contains(u)))
                {
                    <td><a type="button" class="btn edit-btn" href="#user-editor" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a></td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried Bootstrap modal popUp?[check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730644/how-to-create-a-simple-bootstrap-modal-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc/37730969)

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid what do you mean with Bootstrap popUp? Bootstrap Popover? Can you provide more details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a testing sample which will help you understand how can you achieve this.
`Index.cshtml` which will show a list of employees

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Employee>
@using MvcApplication1.Models;
<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
@foreach (Employee item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(@item.EmployeeName, "Name", new { id = item.ID })</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" data-id='@item.ID' class="anchorDetail btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
         data-target="#myModal">
                Open Large Modal</button></td>
    </tr>
 }
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

At the same page, reference the following scripts

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

`JQuery AJAX` call for getting/setting the data of individual employee from `ActionMethod` at the same page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Employee/Details';
    $(document).on('click', '.anchorDetail', function () {
        var $buttonClicked = $(this);
        var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
        var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { "Id": id },
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                $('.modal-body').html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal(options);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    });
    $("#closbtn").click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Now Create a class of Employee(because i'm not using EF)

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

Create controller named Employee and 2 ActionMethods like these:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(emp);//sends a List of employees to Index View
}
public ActionResult Details(int Id)
{
  return PartialView("Details", 
  emp.Where(x=>x.ID==Convert.ToInt32(Id)).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

I'm returning `PartialView` because I need to load a page within a page.
`Details.cshtml`

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Employee
<fieldset>
<legend>Employee</legend>
<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
</div>
<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
</div>
</fieldset>
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</p>
```

When you execute and visit the Index page of Employee, you'll see screen like this:

[image: Index View]

And the Modal Dialog with results will be shown like this:

[image: Modal Dialog]

**Note: You need to add reference of jquery and Bootstrap and you can further design/customize it according to your needs**

Hope it helps!

Comment: I imagined it was impossible without jQuery. This is helpful, thank you!